# Issue with creating bitnami-docker-redis-cluster

Tags: docker, redis, bitnami, redis-cluster

When I try to execute the docker command getting the below error:

docker run --name redis-cluster -e ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes bitnami/redis-cluster:latest

```
latest: Pulling from bitnami/redis-cluster
Digest: sha256:f987a4d7135803e5a69facde40c8cdb451fd599bd3527dc4f9c87a10610b0f48
Status: Downloaded newer image for bitnami/redis-cluster:latest
redis-cluster 10:05:56.01
redis-cluster 10:05:56.01 Welcome to the Bitnami redis-cluster container
redis-cluster 10:05:56.01 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-cluster
redis-cluster 10:05:56.01 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-cluster/issues
redis-cluster 10:05:56.02
redis-cluster 10:05:56.02 INFO  ==> ** Starting Redis setup **
redis-cluster 10:05:56.04 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
redis-cluster 10:05:56.04 ERROR ==> REDIS_NODES is required
```

Comment: [[ -z "$REDIS_NODES" ]] && print_validation_error "REDIS_NODES is required" from https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-cluster/blob/master/6.0/debian-10/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/librediscluster.sh => REDIS_NODES env variable is mandatory, add it on your docker run

Comment: You need to configure the cluster using the REDIS_NODES environment variable as @KristofDcu says. Check this docker-compose file for an example of a deployment: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-cluster/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 3):

[updated compose file is here](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/redis-cluster/docker-compose.yml)

should be sth. like this, for one node:

```
  redis:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.0
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
      REDIS_NODES: redis
      REDIS_CLUSTER_CREATOR: yes
```

btw, they really should fix their doc.